# Measuring how much memory is available in C# + Mono

Tags: c#, windows, memory, ubuntu, mono

I would like to measure how much of system's memory is available in my `C#` code. I believe it is done something like this:

```
PerformanceCounter ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter(
    "Memory"
    , "Available MBytes"
    , true
);
float availbleRam = ramCounter.NextValue();
```

The thing is `Mono` has no `"Memmory"` category. I iterated over the list of categories like this:

```
PerformanceCounterCategory[] cats = PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories();
string res = "";
foreach (PerformanceCounterCategory c in cats)
{
    res += c.CategoryName + Environment.NewLine;
}
return res;
```

And closest category I found is `"Mono Memory"` which has no `"Available MBytes"` and keeps returning 0 on `NextValue` calls. Here's the complete list of categories mono returns:

```
Processor
Process
Mono Memory
ASP.NET
.NET CLR JIT
.NET CLR Exceptions
.NET CLR Memory
.NET CLR Remoting
.NET CLR Loading
.NET CLR LocksAndThreads
.NET CLR Interop
.NET CLR Security
Mono Threadpool
Network Interface
```

So does anyone know a way to measure the available memory in `C#` + `Mono` + `Ubuntu`?

**[UPDATE]**

I managed to do this in `Ubuntu` like this (using the external program `free`):

```
long GetFreeMemorySize()
{
    Regex ram_regex = new Regex(@"[^\s]+\s+\d+\s+(\d+)$");
    ProcessStartInfo ram_psi = new ProcessStartInfo("free");
    ram_psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    ram_psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
    ram_psi.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    ram_psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    System.Diagnostics.Process free = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ram_psi);
    using (System.IO.StreamReader myOutput = free.StandardOutput)
    {
        string output = myOutput.ReadToEnd();
        string[] lines = output.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        lines[2] = lines[2].Trim();
        Match match = ram_regex.Match(lines[2]);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            try
            {
                return Convert.ToInt64(match.Groups[1].Value);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return 0L;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return 0L;
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem with this solution is that it works with `Mono` only if it is run within a `Linux` system. I would like to know if anyone can come up with a solution for `Mono` + `Windows`?

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question, but my answer might help someone.

You need to find out what performance categories and counters are available on your system.

```
foreach (var cat in PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories())
{
    Console.WriteLine(cat.CategoryName + ":");
    foreach (var co in cat.GetCounters())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(co.CounterName);
    }                
}
```

Then you will need to use the corresponding values for measuring the performance.

For Windows, those should be:

```
var memory = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
```

For Linux (tested on Yogurt 0.2.3):

```
var memory = new PerformanceCounter("Mono Memory", "Available Physical Memory");
```

The values might be different depending on the operating system, but you will find the correct values by iterating the categories and the counters for each category.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

Place that after your first "NextValue" call (you can toss the very first NextValue return value) and follow it with your line:

```
float availbleRam = ramCounter.NextValue();
```

Performance counters need time to measure before they can return results.

Confirmed this works in Windows with .net 4.5, unsure about Linux with Mono.

Comment: You realize "using Mono, not .NET" was the most important thing in the whole question, right?

Comment: I do; however, this should work in Mono too.  It's a common mistake in plain old .Net so I'm assuming it is the same thing here.  I encourage Mehran to try it and let us know if this solves the issue or not.